# (Java) data structure for fast insertion, deletion, and RANDOM SELECTION

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, data-structures, hashset

I need a data structure that supports the following operations in **O(1)**:

1. myList.**add(Item)**
2. myList.**remove(Item.ID)**  ==> It actually requires random access
3. myList.**getRandomElement()** (with equal probability)

   --(**Please note that getRandomElement() does not mean random access, it just means: "Give me one of the items at random, with equal probability"**)

Note that my items are unique, so I don't care if a *List* or *Set* is used.
I checked some java data structures, but it seems that none of them is the solution:

1. **HashSet** supports 1,2 in O(1), but it cannot give me a random element in O(1). I need to call **mySet.iterator().next()** to select a random element, which takes O(n).
2. **ArrayList** does 1,3 in O(1), but it needs to do a linear search to find the element I want to delete, though it takes O(n)

Any suggestions? Please tell me which functions should I call?

**If java does not have such data structure, which algorithm should I use for such purpose?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use combination of **HashMap** and **ArrayList** if memory permits as follows:-

> 1. Store numbers in ArrayList arr as they come.
> 2. Use HashMap to give mapping  arr[i] => i
> 3. While generating random select random form arrayList

**Deleting :-**

> 1. check in HashMap for num => i
> 2. swap(i,arr.size()-1)
> 3. HashMap.remove(num)
> 4. HashMap(arr[i])=> i
> 5. arr.remove(arr.size()-1)

All operation are `O(1)` but extra `O(N)` space

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `HashMap` (of ID to array index) in conjunction with an array (or `ArrayList`).

`add` could be done in O(1) by simply adding to the array and adding the ID and index to the `HashMap`.

`remove` could be done in O(1) by doing a lookup (and removal) from the `HashMap` to find the index, then move the last index in the array to that index, update that element's index in the `HashMap` and decreasing the array size by one.

`getRandomElement` could be done in O(1) by returning a random element from the array.

**Example:**

```
Array: [5,3,2,4]
HashMap: [5->0, 3->1, 2->2, 4->3]
```

To remove 3:

```
Look up (and remove) key 3 in the HashMap (giving 3->1)
Swap 3 and, the last element, 4 in the array
Update 4's index in the HashMap to 1
Decrease the size of the array by 1

Array: [5,4,2]
HashMap: [5->0, 2->2, 4->1]
```

To add 6:

```
Simply add it to the array and HashMap

Array: [5,4,2,6]
HashMap: [5->0, 2->2, 4->1, 6->3]
```

Comment: same answer in same time :)

Comment: I like this one best because it has examples and more detailed text.